# How to iterate each row according to values of row above?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

Suppose sensors are attached to 3 climbers scaling a structure and these sensors capture a certain measurement at random times. The data are captured into the data frame below (the data frame is a lot longer than this):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Name': ['Cody', 'Dustin', 'Dustin', 'Cody', 'Ryan', 'Dustin', 'Ryan', 'Cody'],
'Timestamp': ['08:10:23', '08:12:58', '08:15:02', '08:19:43', '08:21:00', '08:30:17', '08:34:01', '08:34:59'],
'Category': ['Body Temp', 'Altitude', 'Heart Rate', 'Body Temp', 'Heart Rate', 'Heart Rate', 'Altitude', 'Altitude'],
'Body Temp': [35.9, np.nan, np.nan, 36.2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
'Altitude': [np.nan, 7, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 12, 6],
'Heart Rate': [np.nan, np.nan, 75, np.nan, 71, 69, np.nan, np.nan]
})

     Name Timestamp    Category  Body Temp  Altitude  Heart Rate
0    Cody  08:10:23   Body Temp       35.9       NaN         NaN
1  Dustin  08:12:58    Altitude        NaN       7.0         NaN
2  Dustin  08:15:02  Heart Rate        NaN       NaN        75.0
3    Cody  08:19:43   Body Temp       36.2       NaN         NaN
4    Ryan  08:21:00  Heart Rate        NaN       NaN        71.0
5  Dustin  08:30:17  Heart Rate        NaN       NaN        69.0
6    Ryan  08:34:01    Altitude        NaN      12.0         NaN
7    Cody  08:34:59    Altitude        NaN       6.0         NaN
```

The intention is to constantly update the measurements at every row, according to each climber and timestamp, such that every succeeding row for each climber will have their measurements updated.

So a result should look something like this:

```
     Name Timestamp    Category  Body Temp  Altitude  Heart Rate
0    Cody  08:10:23   Body Temp       35.9       NaN         NaN
1  Dustin  08:12:58    Altitude        NaN       7.0         NaN
2  Dustin  08:15:02  Heart Rate        NaN       7.0        75.0
3    Cody  08:19:43   Body Temp       36.2       NaN         NaN
4    Ryan  08:21:00  Heart Rate        NaN       NaN        71.0
5  Dustin  08:30:17  Heart Rate        NaN       7.0        69.0
6    Ryan  08:34:01    Altitude        NaN      12.0        71.0
7    Cody  08:34:59    Altitude       36.2       6.0         NaN
```

So far I've thought of using `.sort_value()` to separate the climbers and work from there. But I have trouble figuring out how to update each row continually. Are functions or iterrows required for this?

Comment: Any reason for having an extra column of `Category`? I am asking because you have those categories as columns also.

Comment: It's a column to indicate which category of data the sensor is capturing. For example, if the 'Category' states 'Altitude', it means that there is a new 'Altitude' data that have been entered into the data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The job essentially seems to be filling missing values by a previous value if such value exists at that measurement for each climber, so `groupby.ffill` should do the job:

```py
out = df[['Name']].join(df.groupby('Name').ffill())
```

Output:

```
     Name Timestamp    Category  Body Temp  Altitude  Heart Rate
0    Cody  08:10:23   Body Temp       35.9       NaN         NaN
1  Dustin  08:12:58    Altitude        NaN       7.0         NaN
2  Dustin  08:15:02  Heart Rate        NaN       7.0        75.0
3    Cody  08:19:43   Body Temp       36.2       NaN         NaN
4    Ryan  08:21:00  Heart Rate        NaN       NaN        71.0
5  Dustin  08:30:17  Heart Rate        NaN       7.0        69.0
6    Ryan  08:34:01    Altitude        NaN      12.0        71.0
7    Cody  08:34:59    Altitude       36.2       6.0         NaN
```

Comment: It works, thank you! But if you don't mind, could you break down what is happening in that line of code there?

Comment: @Code_Curious `ffill` fills forward, so for each climber in each row, each succeeding missing measurement is filled with the previous non-NaN value. For example, Dustin's heart rate at altitude is missing, but his altitude measurements were measured 3 mins ago, so the altitude measurement is filled forward, i.e. the previously measured value is used to fill the missing measurement.

Comment: Hey @NewbieAF - what happened to your account?